# Error in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, properties, undefined

I have this component in angular:

```html
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-login-modal',
    templateUrl: './login123.component.html'
})
export class JhiLoginModalComponent implements AfterViewInit {
   a: number;
   @ViewChild('hiddenLabel') hidden: ElementRef;
     ngAfterViewInit() {
      const a = 5;
      console.log('Print a' + a);
     console.log('Print htmlcontent' + this.hidden);
   }
}
```

My HTML file is like this:

```html
<label #hiddenLabel>Visible!</label>
```

And then I have a testing file for these where I want to test the html element. But firstly I want to make sure that I can print it and then test the value. Here is my test file:

```html
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { JhiLoginModalComponent } from '../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared/login/login.component';

describe('Component Tests', () => {
    describe('LoginComponent', () => {

        let comp: JhiLoginModalComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<JhiLoginModalComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [JhiLoginModalComponent]
            })
            .overrideTemplate(JhiLoginModalComponent, '')
            .compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JhiLoginModalComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
        });
        it ('first test', async(() => {
            console.log('holaaa');
            fixture.detectChanges();
        }));
    });
});
```

What I get as a result in my console is that test passed. Normally this should be ok. And then it prints holaaa and then print a5 which is again alright. Then it prints Print htmlcontentundefined instead of printing Visible. What is the difference between teh number and teh HTMLElement?? Is there another way to reference the HTML elements?? As much as I have read on this it should be this way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your `hiddenLabel` child is `undefined`, meaning it is not being picked up by your component typescript spec file. This is due to the `.overrideTemplate(JhiLoginModalComponent, '')`. This line replaces your `JhiLoginModalComponent` template with nothing. Thus, when your `JhiLoginModalComponent` trys to get the `hiddenLabel` viewChild it cannot find anything, therefore it is `undefined`.

You should change your spec to look like the following:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async, inject, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { JhiLoginModalComponent } from '../../../../../../main/webapp/app/shared/login/login.component';

describe('Component Tests', () => {
    describe('LoginComponent', () => {

        let comp: JhiLoginModalComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<JhiLoginModalComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                declarations: [JhiLoginModalComponent]
            }).compileComponents();
        }));

        beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(JhiLoginModalComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            fixture.detectChanges();
        });
        it ('first test', async(() => {
            console.log('holaaa');
            fixture.detectChanges();
        }));
    });
});
```